# How to check if user is logged in with new facebook php api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am migrating my old FB app to the new graph API using the [PHP API](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)

I have two pages: public ones (which require no user login) and private ones (which do)

So the code of every single php page in my application works as follows:

```
if (this_page_requires_user_login){
      $facebook = new Facebook(...) ;
      $session = $facebook->getSession ;
      if (!$session){
              $url =$facebook.getLoginUrl(array(next => current_page );
              echo "<fb:redirect url=$url/>" ;

}
// the rest of the code continues here
```

Now as you can see, this way of working forwards every single page to the login url and while it works, it is also slow and appends the &session={bla} string to very single url.

I need a way to check where a user is already logged in before I redirect him to loginpage. But i can not find such method in the php api. What's the best way to do this?

**EDIT**

This seemed to do the trick

```
if ($session) {
  try {
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    if ($me) {
       // here comes your code for user who is logged in
    }
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    login()
  }
}else{
 login()
}

function login(){

  $url =$facebook.getLoginUrl(array(next => current_page );


      echo "<fb:redirect url=$url/>" ;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I am reading your code correctly, only if no session is returned do you do the redirect? According to comments in [Facebook's example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php), even if you get a session back, you can't assume it's still valid. Only trying an API call that requires a logged in user will you know for sure. This is the best way I've seen to  reliably determine login/logout status.

```
if ($session) {
  try {
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    if ($me) {
      //User is logged in
    }
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    //User is not logged in
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have stored the access token and are using it, this doesn't work, because the API call still works without throwing an exception, but then when you redirect them to the getLogoutUrl for example, it just sends them to Facebook's homepage, instead of sending you back to your website

Comment: You had to decode the url before, thats why you don´t redirected:
<?php echo rawurlencode($logoutUrl); ?>