# Is it possibile to check within php if a user is logged in facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

I would like to give the opportunity to post a comment to my website user. To make stuff easier I want give them the opportuinity to login with their facebook account.

But I don't get how Can i check if they are logged within my php?

**Note: I don't want to use their comments-plugin.**

A sample code would be:

```
<?php

   $fb = new Facebook();
   if ($fb->user->isLogged()) {
     //> Insert the comment in my database
   }

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use the plugins available for this scenario?

Comment: How does this question differ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244912/how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-in-with-new-facebook-php-api or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654473/check-if-a-user-is-logged-in-to-facebook

Comment: There do seem to be ways to fix your SEO problem (although it could be construed as a feature, not a bug, to prevent spam links from sinking your rating).  The following seems to be for .Net but you may be able to adjust it for php. http://www.mattcashatt.com/post/index/Search-Engine-Optimization-With-Facebook-Comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to pull the comment for SEO purposes then Facebook has a "small" tutorial about this [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490).

Also in the [comment plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) FAQ section, there is a a question/answer about this:

> **How can I get an SEO boost from the comments left on my site?**
>   The Facebook comments box is rendered in
>   an iframe on your page, and most
>   search engines will not crawl content
>   within an iframe. However, you can
>   access all the comments left on your
>   site via the graph API as described
>   above. Simply grab the comments from
>   the API and render them in the body of
>   your page behind the comments box. We
>   recommend you cache the results, as
>   pulling the comments from the graph
>   API on each page load could slow down
>   the rendering time of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Add a connect with facebook button on your site and, once the user approve your application's access to their stuff, you will receive facebook cookies.

```
<?php

require './facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR APP ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR API SECRET',
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));


if ($facebook->getSession()) {
  echo '<a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">Logout</a>';
} else {
  echo '<a href="' . $facebook->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}
```

copied from https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/readme.md

Comment: YES! Here you can find how to create an application. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/